# imagettftext проблема с русскими символами

Tags: php, изображения, gd

пытаюсь вывести русский текст на картинку.
файл в кодировке utf8.
Но все равно кракозября выводит. уже кучу рецептов в интернетах посмотрел. советуют кодировать перекодировать. все уже пробовал. да и не надо по идее кодировать. итак же все в utf8.

```
  $fontName = "impact"; // путь к шрифту
  $font_sise = 18;       // размер шрифта
  $textColor = 0x000000; // цвет шрифта
  $x = 50; // отступ слева
  $y = 50; // отступ справа
  $text = 'Текст\n кириллица';
  $arr = imagettftext($img, $font_sise, 0, $x, $y, $textColor, $fontName,$text);
  var_export($arr);
```

Вобще выводит вот так - http://prntscr.com/fga5tc

Comment: Дело было в шрифте! Я скачивал шрифт из инета он весил 60кб. Я чет подумал, мож в нем и нет utf8 символов.... и взял arial из системы, он весит 800кб - и сразу заработало как надо...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать какой-то другой шрифт.
Положите font.ttf в папку с php файлом и импортируйте его так:

```
$fontName = "./font.ttf";
```

Comment: не не помогло, отписал под своим вопросом в чем была проблема

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг то есть без ".ttf" код работает?

Comment: @hivokas [`imagettftext()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagettftext.php). "В зависимости от версии GD библиотеки если fontfile не начинается с /, то в конец названия файла будет добавлено расширение .ttf, и библиотека будет пытаться найти этот файл по адресу, определенному в настройках библиотеки."